# Sound Reporting in Istanbul

Tags: reporting

please, listen and comment

http://www.sun-art.org/soundreporting/soundreportingistanbul/

recorderd with : Zoom H4N and Sennheiser ME66

Answer (score 1):

Welcome, Mario.

Maybe it's the way you've encoded your audio, but everything sounds like it has a severe low-pass filter on it, with not much above 1-2kHz showing up. Regarding the content, not much character or details of interest except for the no.6 Moschea: nice acoustics from the surrounding buildings, and the man has a very intense voice.

Thanks for submitting your work -

Comment: COMMENT PART 1

hello Jay, 
thanks for the technical advice, they are always welcome by those who have much experience in the field of recording...
about the contents of recording, i was not looking for something in particular, but simply wanted to photograph a daily routine or part of it, especially on this trip that I made in Istanbul ...for example  in the street market , the taxi driver listening to local radio, the evocative call to prayer in mosques etc. etc. etc.

MARIOLINO

Comment: COMMENT PART 2
Generally, when you travel you used to fix the memories through images (pictures/VIdeo), but after seeing these materials makes the experience a "passive" act (especially for those who have not experienced directly the experience of travel, which were not present on the spot). Instead of listening to audio materials makes the experience an "active" act  that stimulates the imagination (such as reading a book).

MARIOLINO

Comment: COMMENT PART 3 (THE END) 
From these personal considerations on the practice of recording audio outdoors, i created a section on my website called "Sound Reporting" (www.sun-art.org/category/soundreporting/)
 [I ask mercy for my poor English :)]
  MARIOLINO